# Cannot update filter controls, PivotTables, PivotCharts, or cube functions

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable connection to a SSAS tabular model.  After I saved it and reopened it, the PivotTable became completely unresponsive.

What I mean by unresponsive is that I can't Refresh data, I can't add remove columns or rows or values, I can't even change properties on the data source connection, I can't even change the connection to something new.  I never get a message or progress bar or anything.  I can also still edit other cells that aren't part of the Pivot Table.

If I copy and paste the PivotTable into a new workbook then everything works again.  But once I save it, and reopen it the same problem occurs.

I have lots of other workbooks with PivotTables that connect to the same model without any problem.

Finally I got a clue.  I deleted a slicer and received the following message:

```
Cannot update filter controls, PivotTables, PivotCharts, or cube functions.

Reasons for this can include:
  * The connection to the data source failed.
  * The worksheet is protected
  * A PivotTable cannot expand because it would overlap existing cell content
```

It's definitely not the third reason, and I didn't place any protections on the worksheet.  The fact that I can not edit the connection might mean it's related to the first item since I can't edit the connection at all.  More likely this is just a generic message.

Has anybody encountered this before?

If not, what's a good way to debug this?

**UPDATE**

This seems to be happening with every new Workbook with connected PivotTable that I create!  But if I edit and save older ones I don't have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem I needed to go *Excel Options* > *Trust Center* > *Trust Center Settings* > *External Content*.

In External Content I had **Security settings for Data Connections** and set to **Disable all Data Connections**.  Changing that to **Prompt user about Data Connections** fixed my problem.

I don't remember ever setting that to disable, and I used to get a prompt when I opened Worksheets from the network.  So it's weird that was changed.  It would be nice to get an error message indicated this was the problem.